# Distinguish accepted application request from not yet accepted on facebook

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-apps

I'm developing a game for Facebook.
I use application requests, also known as invites.

I'm wondering if there is a way to distinguish accepted application request from not yet accepted. After a user accepts the request, I delete it via DELETE call to Graph API as described  in documentation http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/requests/ (section Deleting Requests). But I still can GET the application request using GraphAPI.

The root issue is the following. I check the presence of "request_ids" HTTP-param in every incoming HTTP-request and perform app-request processing/deleting if the param is present. So, if the user came to my application by an invite link and hit F5, another HTTP-request still containing same "request_ids" param will be sent to my application. Here I would like to know if the application request has already been processed.

Of course I can track it in my database. But Im looking for some solution using facebook APIs.

Would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 0):

> Of course I can track it in my database. But Im looking for some
>   solution using facebook APIs.

Why? on the same link you posted, it's make clear that it's **your** responsibility:

> When a user is directed to your application, by clicking a Request
>   from the application, the games dashboard, or from a Request
>   notification, you **must** delete the request after it has been accepted.
>   **Requests are not automatically deleted once they have been clicked**,
>   thus it is the **developer’s responsibility** to clear them once they have
>   been consumed.

Now I thought that issuing a `DELETE` request to a user specific apprequest would actually invalidate future `GET` calls for this particular apprequest. But even if that's not the case, you should be handling such cases.

Comment: > it's make clear that it's your responsibility
I know. I do delete the requests.

> But even if that's not the case
Yes, unfortunatelly that's not the case

> you should be handling such cases
This is what my question actually was about.

Comment: I know :-) so long story short: `Of course I can track it in my database. But Im looking for some solution using facebook APIs.` YOU **CAN'T**